# Generic unboxing of Expression<Func<T, object>> to Expression<Func<T, TResult>>

Tags: c#, generics

As mentioned in the title I have an Expression where the result type is 'stored' in an `object`, which can be **all** of my domain classes. Is there a way to get the concrete expression (unboxing)?

Comment: What kind of expressions could be used in lambda's body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what you might be looking for is [Expression.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Expression<Func<T,object>> original = // ... something
Expression<Func<T,TResult>> converted = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,TResult>>(
        Expression.Convert(original.Body,typeof(TResult)), 
        original.Parameters);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/SkrBWx)

Comment: Thank you, thats working! But still one question: When I need this unboxed expression I don't know the type of TResult (beside that is implementing IPersistable). I could remember/getting the type and packing the call `Unbox<T,????>(f1)` in a switch case expression. But do you know a more comfortable way?

Comment: How would you want to get a Func<T,TResult> if you dont know what TResult is ? Do you at least have a System.Type object representing TResult ?

Comment: To getting or holding the type would be no problem. But could this question be worth for a new thread?

Comment: What I meant is: What is the use of getting a Expression<Func<T,TResult>> if are not in a statically typed context for TResult type ? (you wont be able to use it as a proper Func<T,TResult> !)
If you're only interested by the Expression, just use Expression.Lambda() without generic argument (and assign it to "Expression" type only)