# Removing an unneeded boxing convert from a c# expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, boxing, unboxing

I'm currently trying to convert an

```
Expression<Func<T,object>>
```

to an

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>>
```

Currently the watch shows me that my expression holds

```
Expression<Func<T,object>> myExpression = model=>Convert(model.IsAnAirplane)
```

I'd like to simplify this to

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> myExpression = model=>model.IsAnAirplane
```

Currently I only succeed at adding a convert, resulting in:

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> myExpression = model=>Convert(Convert(model.IsAnAirplane))
```

But since the underlying type IS a bool, I should be able to scratch the converts entirely, right? I'm familiar with expression visitors etc, but still can't figure out how to remove the convert.

Edit: this accepted answer to this question [Generic unboxing of Expression<Func<T, object>> to Expression<Func<T, TResult>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744612/generic-unboxing-of-expressionfunct-object-to-expressionfunct-tresult) (that could be a possible duplicate) doesn't work for me ... as the expression gets translated by EF, you can see it does Convert(Convert()) instead of just removing the first convert... , this results in "Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to strip out any `Convert` wrappers using something like this:

```
Expression<Func<YourModel, object>> boxed = m => m.IsAnAirplane;

var unboxed = (Expression<Func<YourModel, bool>>)StripConvert(boxed);

// ...

public static LambdaExpression StripConvert<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> source)
{
    Expression result = source.Body;
    // use a loop in case there are nested Convert expressions for some crazy reason
    while (((result.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
               || (result.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
           && (result.Type == typeof(object)))
    {
        result = ((UnaryExpression)result).Operand;
    }
    return Expression.Lambda(result, source.Parameters);
}
```

If you prefer, you could alter `StripConvert` to return `Expression<Func<T,U>>` instead of a plain `LambdaExpression` and perform the cast inside the method itself, but in that case you wouldn't be able to take advantage of type-inferencing for the method call.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, and works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this really saved my butt

Comment: Please provide a sample of how to get Expression<Func<T,U>>.
(Expression<Func<T,T2>>) Expression.Lambda(result, source.Parameters);?