# Dynamic Expression Generation Issues with ValueTypes

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, linq-expressions

I built a framework that allows for cascaded sorting of report data in a table depending on what column is the master sorted column.  It works for the most part, except in one specific, but important case:  when the field's property is a value type.  I receive the following error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

I know that this means I need to box the value of the ValueType, but I'm not completely sure how to in this particular situation.  Per some research and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20745242/2359643) I believe that I need to use [`Expression.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) in some way.

My code below is what generates the expressions.  The generic type parameter T is the type of the "row" of data.  The `GetFullSortOrder()` simply returns an array of strings that represent the names of the columns (properties) in the type T that will also be sorted.

```
public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> GetExpressions<T>(string sortedColumn) where T : IReportRecord
    {
        var columns = GetFullSortOrder(sortedColumn)
        var typeParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        foreach (var c in columns)
        {
            var propParameter = Expression.Property(typeParameter, c);
            yield return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propParameter, typeParameter);
        }
    }
```

The exception is thrown when processing `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>()` when the Property selected in T is of a ValueType.  What is needed to property box or return the correct value when the types aren't known until run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it - you need to use [`Expression.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `typeof(object)`. If you want to simulate what the C# compiler does, you should do it only for value types:

```
Expression result = propParameter;
if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
    result = Expression.Convert(result, typeof(object));
yield return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(result, typeParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your property `Expression` to an object type:

```
var propParameterObj = Expression.Convert(propParameter, typeof(object));
```

Comment: And then use that in the `Expression.Lambda<>()` call?

Comment: @JNYRanger yes, i would do it for every parameter, but perhaps converting for ref types is not neccessery

Comment: Yeah It's def not necessary for reference types, but I'll optimize it later on once things are working for all types.