# Boxed Values Using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic, linq-expressions

This is a follow up to my question [Dynamic Expression Generation Issues with ValueTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42032468/2359643) adding in a new variable:  Entity Framework.  Now that I am able to generate the necessary Expressions when dealing with ValueTypes, I'm running into a new issue when Linq-to-Entities attempts to process the query.  I receive the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

So apparently Linq-to-Entities is not a fan of boxed values.  This works when I force the query to process (via `ToList()` or another type method), but not when it's done by the database, which would be ideal.

Is there a way to make this method more generic to make Linq-to-Entities happy?  Keep in mind that I don't know the type of the property until runtime.

```
public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> GetExpressions<T>(string sortedColumn) where T : IReportRecord
{
    var columns = GetFullSortOrder(sortedColumn);
    var typeParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    foreach (var c in columns)
    {
        var propParameter = Expression.Property(typeParameter, c);
        if (propParameter.Type.IsValueType)
        {
            var boxedPropParameter = Expression.Convert(propParameter, typeof(object));
            yield return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(boxedPropParameter, typeParameter);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propParameter, typeParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of generating `Expressions` you can apply your ordering directly to the `IQueryable` dynamically like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet/233505#233505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this issue is the opposite of the previous where you needed `Expression.Convert` when generating `Expression<Func<T, object>>`. Consider a method with the following signature

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> selectors)
```

which has to create `OrderBy` / `ThenBy` chain from the passed selectors. Here you need to **remove** the `Expression.Convert` needed only to make possible converting `Expression<Func<T, V>>` to `Expression<Func<T, object>>` for value type `V`.

Let create a small helper methods for both conversions:

```
public static Expression Wrap(this Expression source)
{
    if (source.Type.IsValueType)
        return Expression.Convert(source, typeof(object));
    return source;
}

public static LambdaExpression Unwrap<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> source)
{
    var body = source.Body;
    if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
    return Expression.Lambda(body, source.Parameters);
}
```

Now the implementation of the original method could be simply

```
public static IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> GetExpressions<T>(string sortedColumn) where T : IReportRecord
{
    var typeParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return from c in GetFullSortOrder(sortedColumn)
           select Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
                Expression.Property(typeParameter, c).Wrap(), typeParameter);
}
```

and the applying method could be something like this

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> keySelectors)
{
    var result = source.Expression;
    var method = "OrderBy";
    foreach (var item in keySelectors)
    {
        var keySelector = item.Unwrap();
        result = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), method, new[] { typeof(T), keySelector.Body.Type },
            result, Expression.Quote(keySelector));
        method = "ThenBy";
    }
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(result);
}
```

Of course it doesn't need to be that way. In your case you could combine the two methods in one (similar to the second, but receiving `string sortedColumn`), in which case you will simply use the non generic `Expression.Lambda` method without wrapping the value types with `Convert`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, perfect!  Thanks Ivan!  The only difference is that instead of using the extension methods I just had the `GetExpressions` method return the non-generic version as you suggested.  Works swimmingly!